# Parsing List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
l =  [{'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': ‘pass’} , {'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': ‘pass’},  {'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': ‘pass’,},{'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': ‘pending’}]
```

I want to check if there are any dictionaries with a "pending" order status in the list of dictionaries. How can I check if there are any dictionaries with a "pending" order status in the whole list?

Comment: `pending = [o for o in l if o['orderstatus'] == 'pending']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` to transform the list into a list of booleans, where an element is `True` only if its corresponding dictionary has an order status of pending. Then, use `any()` to see if any of the generated booleans are `True`:

```py
data =  [{'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': 'pass'} , {'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': 'pass'},  {'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': 'pass',},{'variety': 'NORMAL', 'orderstatus': 'pending'}]

print(any(map(lambda x: x['orderstatus'] == 'pending', data))) # Prints True
```

Answer (score 1):

use `list comprehension`:

```
res = [i for i in l if i['orderstatus'] == 'pending']
print(res)
```

or using loop:

```
for i in l:
    if i['orderstatus']:
        # do something
```